# Converting HTML Entities (like &amp;) to Latex

Tags: java, html, encoding, utf-8, latex

I'm writing an application to crawl some articles from a website using Java and JSOAP. The application compiles some sections of the article into a .tex ([LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/)) document and then use PDFLatex to convert it to PDF.

Some of the pages contain HTML entities like & or " and these are causing errors during the PDF conversion. How do I workaround this problem?

Comment: &amp is not an UTF8 character, it's an html entity

Comment: UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding. You are describing character entities - these are HTML/XML/SGML entities and have nothing to do with Unicode.

Comment: to be fair the entity is `&amp;` and not `&amp`

Comment: please fix your question to prevent further downvoting; for a start the title should be "converting html entities to latex characters". also please fix use the word entities when you refer to things as `&amp;`, they're NOT utf8 characters.

Comment: @oded not true by any means, they have nothing to do with utf8; but each named entity directly represents an unicode character. unicode != utf8, even if they're used synonymously.

Answer (score 1):

[This question on tex-exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37126/how-can-i-map-html-named-entities-to-latex-commands) has a link to a [neat conversion list](https://gist.github.com/1431606). 
the columns are (in order):

1. html entities (ignoring case), without the `&` and the `;`
2. corresponding unicode character
3. corresponding latex command (if available). without the `\`

it should be quite easy to write some conversion code with this list as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks to everyone to help. I am new here so I can not add reputation, Sorry for that also.

Answer (score 0):

HTML structures data with the use of *tags*, which are defined by a sequence of characters.  Those tags start with and contain certain characters, and if you want to use one of the characters that delimit portions of tags, you need to represent them using a [character entity](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp).

That means that `&amp;` is not some sort of weird encoding of a single character, it is actually five characters which in combination are a signal to an HTML renderer (like a web browser) that only the character `&` is to be displayed.

Tex, is a different beast, and it doesn't have the same restrictions about using a "naked" `&` as HTML does, so before processing such data with Tex, you need to do a string replacement of all HTML character entities with regular characters.

Note that there are two *types* of character entities.  One set includes the "named" entities, like `&gt;` and `&lt;` (`>` and `<`, respectively) while the second set is the "numbered" entities.  Numbered entities look like `&#32;` and the "32" in this example refers to the ISO-8859-1 character code (space in this case).

Comment: @user1656201 That's fine, it happens to everyone.  Good luck with your effort.

Comment: Sorry for above confusion. To solve this I replace all the usual entities to equal latex code.For example "&quot" by "'". Now It works fine.